# How to concate rows as single column in derby

Tags: derby

I use listagg function in Oracle to concate rows in Oracle.

Example:  tables is 
Username 
Abc
Xyz
Pqr

After using listagg in Oracle I get result as 
Abc,Xyz,Pqr

But not able to create same result in derby.  What could be query to get same result

Comment: AFAIK there is no equivalent of listagg in derby. Why not do it in your application code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have tried anything then update your original post to include it. If you dont try then we cant help as we have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Syfer - there's not much scope of trying for this question

Comment: You might be able to add your own. https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevspecialuda.html